# Keyboard in the way of textfields how to move view up

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I am using Xcode's SplitView template.

I have placed a bunch of text fields on the 'detail' side of the view however I forgot about the keyboard taking up half the screen.

How do I move this detail view up when the keyboard comes onto the screen?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I used this solution from the always-useful [Cocoa With Love](http://cocoawithlove.com/2008/10/sliding-uitextfields-around-to-avoid.html) when I could not use a UIScrollView.

If you want to add a UIScrollView you your hierarchy, it gets even easier.  Just insert the UIScrollview in the hierarchy above the text fields and use this code when the user taps the text item to begin editing:

```
UIScrollView* v = (UIScrollView*) self.view ;
CGRect rc = [textField bounds];
    rc = [textField convertRect:rc toView:v];
rc.origin.x = 0 ;
rc.origin.y -= 60 ;

rc.size.height = 400;

[self.scroll scrollRectToVisible:rc animated:YES];
```

Good Luck!

Answer (score 1):

I had that problem once. My app used a table view to show the fields, so the solution I came up with is to listen the textViewDidBeginEditing to perform a scrollToRowAtIndexPath on the table view:

```
- (void)textViewDidBeginEditing:(UITextView *)textView{
    UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell*) [[textView superview] superview];    
    [self.myTableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:[self.myTableView indexPathForCell:cell] atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionMiddle animated:YES];
}
```

If you don't have a table view but a scroll view I think you could take same similar approach but telling the scrollview to scroll to the section you need just as @MystikSpiral told.