# how UITextField should come up in UIScrollView?

Tags: iphone, uiscrollview

I have a UIScrollView, added as

```
[self.view addSubview:myScrollView];
```

There are 8 to 10 UITextFields, so when I click textFields for writing something, they Keyboard comes on them, and they became back to keyboard, now what should I do so that they will look after keyboard end ???

If someone is not clear, may ask again ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pls go through these

[How to make a UITextField move up when keyboard is present?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1126726/how-to-make-a-uitextfield-move-up-when-keyboard-is-present)

[Keyboard in the way of textfields how to move view up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4658654/keyboard-in-the-way-of-textfields-how-to-move-view-up)

[iPhone Keyboard Covers UITextField](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1247113/iphone-keyboard-covers-text-field)

[How programmatically move a UIScrollView to focus in a control above keyboard?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/484855/how-programatically-move-a-uiscrollview-to-focus-in-a-control-above-keyboard)

Answer (score 2):

This is how your .h file should look like

```
@interface LoginScreen : UIViewController <UITextFieldDelegate> 
{
...
UITextField *textView;
CGFloat animatedDistance;
}
```

//put this in your viewcontroller.m file

```
-(void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField{

    static const CGFloat KEYBOARD_ANIMATION_DURATION = 0.3;
    static const CGFloat MINIMUM_SCROLL_FRACTION = 0.2;
    static const CGFloat MAXIMUM_SCROLL_FRACTION = 0.8;
    static const CGFloat PORTRAIT_KEYBOARD_HEIGHT = 216;
    static const CGFloat LANDSCAPE_KEYBOARD_HEIGHT = 162;

    CGRect textFieldRect =
    [self.view convertRect:textField.bounds fromView:textField];
    CGRect viewRect =
    [self.view convertRect:self.view.bounds fromView:self.view];

    CGFloat midline = textFieldRect.origin.y + 0.5 * textFieldRect.size.height;
    CGFloat numerator = midline - viewRect.origin.y - MINIMUM_SCROLL_FRACTION * viewRect.size.height;
    CGFloat denominator = (MAXIMUM_SCROLL_FRACTION - MINIMUM_SCROLL_FRACTION) * viewRect.size.height;
    CGFloat heightFraction = numerator / denominator;
    if (heightFraction < 0.0)
    {
        heightFraction = 0.0;
    }
    else if (heightFraction > 1.0)
    {
        heightFraction = 1.0;
    }

    UIInterfaceOrientation orientation =
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation];
    if (orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait ||
        orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown)
    {
        animatedDistance = floor(PORTRAIT_KEYBOARD_HEIGHT * heightFraction);
    }
    else
    {
        animatedDistance = floor(LANDSCAPE_KEYBOARD_HEIGHT * heightFraction);
    }

    CGRect viewFrame = self.view.frame;
    viewFrame.origin.y -= animatedDistance;

    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState:YES];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:KEYBOARD_ANIMATION_DURATION];

    [self.view setFrame:viewFrame];

    [UIView commitAnimations];

}

 - (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField{

    static const CGFloat KEYBOARD_ANIMATION_DURATION = 0.3;

    CGRect viewFrame = self.view.frame;
    viewFrame.origin.y += animatedDistance;

    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState:YES];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:KEYBOARD_ANIMATION_DURATION];

    [self.view setFrame:viewFrame];

    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
-(BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)txtObject {
    [txtObject resignFirstResponder];

    return YES;
}
```

Comment: Wow... do you really want that much junk cluttering up your view controller...? :/ Why not take the approach of subclassing `UIScrollView` and move some of this logic into it, instead?